# Adding a new node to database, how to automatically update rule-based links

Tags: neo4j, hyperlink, cypher

Please excuse the simplicity of the question perhaps - I am a newbie!

I have a few thousand nodes and a few tens of relationships, but the relationship are largely based on a series of rules and logic.

To explain by example : if I have nodes defined as (c:CAT) and (d:DOG) and each node has a property called size, ie c.size, d.size, etc. then I could quite easily run some Cypher script to set up the relationship between nodes based on the following rule

```
MATCH (c:CAT), (d:DOG) WHERE c.size<d.size
CREATE (c:CAT)-[r:SMALLER_THAN]->(d:DOG)
RETURN c,d
```

This is great and it all works well. Let's assume I now add a new NODE

```
CREATE (c:CAT {type:"tiger", size:"4"})
RETURN c
```

This won't have any links but I want the same logic to apply, ie

```
CREATE (c:CAT)-[r:SMALLER_THAN]->(d:DOG)
```

Do I

1. remove all links and recreate them - ie apply rule to whole system
2. run the same Cypher command as 'MERGE' rather than 'CREATE' therefore assuming that existing relationships won't be modified unless necessary to do so.
3. Find the nodes that have no links and then run the command just on them

I just want to update the links when I add new nodes because, at that time, I know the new node will have no links. Alternatively, should I change the size of a (:CAT) or (:DOG) then the link should be updated automatically.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Could you please adjust your question to avoid confusion for Cypher terminology? For example, you said `size` is a label in your graph, but in this context it's actually a property, a label is something different. Also your Cypher isn't using labels, and it's hard to tell if you meant `CAT` and `DOG` to be labels, or to be variables for specific nodes. Maybe you meant to use :Animal as your label? It's rather unclear your model is supposed to work, as this looks like some kind of taxonomy graph. More details is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only doing this for :CAT and :DOG nodes, you can create the relationships at the same time you create the node:

```
CREATE (c:CAT {type:"tiger", size:"4"})
MATCH (d:DOG)
WHERE c.size < d.size
CREATE (c)-[:SMALLER_THAN]->(d)
```

If you want to create the opposite relationship where it applies, you'll need to use conditionals, either with the FOREACH trick:

```
CREATE (c:CAT {type:"tiger", size:"4"})
WITH c
MATCH (d:DOG)
WITH c, collect(d) as dogs
FOREACH (d in [d in dogs WHERE c.size < d.size] |
 CREATE (c)-[:SMALLER_THAN]->(d))
FOREACH (d in [d in dogs WHERE c.size > d.size] |
 CREATE (c)<-[:SMALLER_THAN]-(d))
```

or you could use APOC conditionals.

As for updating a node's size, you should probably delete all :SMALLER_THAN relationships connected from the node, and then with the distinct node rematch to all possible nodes you want to connect to and create the relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Much appreciated. I think that pretty much deals with the immediate problem. I have a recommendation engine in mind therefore the 'rules' may also be determined by the 'users' of the system ie I don't like 'big cats' but I do like 'small dogs'. Therefore when new nodes are added those links also need to be created. More challenging I suspect, unless individuals can hard-code their rules and behind the scenes it can be codified.

Comment: You may want to think about your use cases to see if this kind of modeling is really what you want. Relationships tend to be used for supporting traversals. If you're doing comparisons instead (such as "give me dogs less than this size" or "is this particular cat smaller than this dog") that's better performed with just comparison of the properties than using those relationships.